# When was this type of dictionary initialization code added to C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, initialization

I just discovered that C# allows dictionary initialization like the code below.  The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx) talks about this further.  I think this is pretty cool, and I'm wondering how long I've been initializing dictionaries the old-fashioned way (a bunch of calls to Add).

When was this type of dictionary initialization added to C#?  I compiled my test program in .Net 4.5, 4.0, 3.5, and 3.0.  I got some weird error when I tried to compile my code with .Net 2.0 but it wasn't related to this dictionary initialization code.

I've been coding C# for years and I've never seen this before today.  I only recently started using .Net 4.5.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Dictionary<int, string> _dc;

    public MyClass()
    {
        this._dc = new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            {1, "one"},
            {2, "two"},
            {3, "three"}
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062(v=vs.90).aspx - VS 2008 which means C# 3

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx#csharp3.0overview_topic12--specific to adding the syntax to c#

Comment: @HenkHolterman I love that they implemented features like that where they should be: The IDE/compiler, not in the framework itself.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Does the compiler turn this code into a bunch of adds in the IL?

Comment: That I wouldn't know, though it seems like that would make sense.

Comment: You could check the IL from both variants to be sure. The IL should be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was introduced with [.NET 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx#csharp3.0overview_topic14).

If you check the revision history of that document you link you will see it goes back to Visual Studio 2008, which was released with .NET 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

It was added from C# 3 and onwards